# How to get a docker image of Gentoo running in windows

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, gentoo

My main target is to have a PI3 B+ running a Gentoo system. First I need a Running Gentoo system to create a system for PI3, and I want to have that Gentoo system running in a Docker environment in win10.

There is a repository containing docker files that creates a Gentoo-image. But those requires that you already have a running Gentoo environment. I thought that it already exists runnable Docker images running Gentoo, am I wrong or where can I find them?

Comment: do you want your RPI to run a Gentoo container, or a Gentoo main operating system?

Comment: The RPI should run Gentoo as a main OS. The container/docker shall run in the windows system.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way I can see is to simply run Gentoo in WSL [this way](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Gentoo_in_WSL) to get your Gentoo "builder" system.

Then you follow [this guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_3_64_bit_Install) to cross-build a RPi Gentoo image.

Note that you'll probably really will not want to emerge significant packages from source on the RPi. The poor thing simply has too little RAM, and unless you attach fast external storage, is based on an SD card, which is not only a slow medium, but also a medium that fails after enough write accesses (it's my personal assessment that by far most of the "my Linux on my RPi suddenly stopped working" posts are due to "ah, well, your SD card has gone into read-only mode, after all wear leveling resources were exhausted").

But that's not a bad thing per se: The "professional" way of deploying and maintaining operating systems for embedded devices is typically, just as the gentoo guide shows, a reliable way to build an image from sources on a proper beefy developer machine, and being able to roll any software you want into that before you bring the image to the device, for reliability, traceability and repeatability reasons.

(must say, though, it would not have hurt if there was an easy to find gentoo image that was ready to boot, should one just want to try something small… but I guess that's a bit against the philosophy of it. Good on them to stick to their ideals!)

Comment: Ok, WSL looks promising I'll try that asap. Interesting what you say about SD-cards. I have a laptop using a SSD as the hard drive. This computer I been using daily for 10 years now without any problem so it couldn't be that bad or..?

Comment: No, an actual SSD is designed for much more write access, and the interfaces computers have to SSDs allow them to tell the computer when they are soon to be in trouble - not so the SD card interface!

Comment: Ok, I understand. That's a good point. A backup SD for the RPI and an external disk as backup for important data should be used I believe.

Comment: @larand what people do that run applications on their pi that regularly need to write data is that they attach an external storage device via USB and directly mount that in place. You can technically even do that with your whole Linux aside from what is necessary to boot, but I don't know how that'd work for Gentoo.